# Wamp server PHPmyadmin page blank

Tags: phpmyadmin, wampserver

When I open phpmyadmin it comes up with a blank page. I have tried lots of different things. I found out skype works on port 80, but it still does not work. I have ran out of ideas. So I took a screen shot of what my problem looks like. Here is the [screen-shot](https://i.imgur.com/YzbMgj3.png).[image]

Comment: Have you checked that other then phpmyadmin, like any php script is executing well, you can try to change the default port of skype or apache

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, there is a colision with the ports between Skype and Wamp server.

My solution was that:

1. Go to Skype -> Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connection
2. Uncheck the option "use port 80 and 443 for additional incoming connections"
3. Save
4. Close Skype and then open it again (restart).
5. Go to Wamp server taskbar icon and select "Restart All Services"

Now, the colision with the ports is fixed.

That worked for me.